# How can I get CSS will to work in EJS file

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

Im doing a small project and trying to get CSS working in ejs/node.
I dont know why it wont load.

[enter image description here][1]

Also having a massive issue with getting images to load.

one file example - -->h

Comment: Questions here about code MUST show that code in your question, pasted in as text and formatted properly.  We can't guess what your code is or isn't doing.  Please show both the nodejs server code and the EJS file and explain where the images/CSS files are in your server-side file system.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are calling the template engine?

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Did you call static files like this.
The name "public" may change depending on your project.